# How to authenticate with Google Drive in asp.net without copy/pasting auth tokens

Tags: asp.net, authorization, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get authorization code for Google Drive in my ASP program.  I wrote some code like quickstart program from sample of Google API for .NET:

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg){
    // Get the auth URL:
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(
         new[] {DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

    //Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
    string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
}
```

I want to get authorization code by opening a popup and user can access permission in this, after user access permission, this return the code.